# Using Ajax with the Yii framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I need to load a page dynamically via something like Ajax. I'm on the Yii 2 framework in PHP.

Basically I just want to click a button and have the contents of another URL appear in a div on the same page. Very basic stuff, but it's not working for me.

I'm trying this code below

```
<p><a id="ajax" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="<?php echo"$url"; ?>">Choose Winner</a></p>


<div id="winner"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ajax').click(function(){
$('#winner').load($(this).attr('href'));
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

And it's not working. $url is the url of the page I want to load.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hey guys, for some reason when I added the jquery library ON TOP of the ajax call it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code. I have change  `href="javascript:void(0);"` and add  `data-url="http://stackoverflow.com"` . You can use your `PHP` code in `data-url="<?php echo '$url'; ?>"`

Here is **UPDATED CODE** :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ajax').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('data-url'));
$('#winner').load($(this).attr('data-url'));
return false;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a id="ajax" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" data-url="http://stackoverflow.com">Choose Winner</a></p>


<div id="winner"></div>
```

Comment: This creates a dialog box that I don't want. It does seem to work though.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason when I added the jquery library ON TOP of the ajax call it worked.